# Does an OnClickListener take into account the scaling factor of the view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-touch-event

I have a `CustomLayout` view that extends `TableLayout` and contains `LinearLayout` row children, each of them containing a `RelativeLayout` cell (each individual cell having an **`OnClickListener`**). The `CustomLayout` also has a `ScaleGestureDetector` present and supports scrolling/dragging on the X/Y axis. Everything works great when the scaling factor is 1 (no scaling).

The **problem** is that each cell's `OnClickListener` doesn't appear to take into account the scaling factor of the `CustomLayout` and subsequently, it's own cell scaling. So if the zoom is 2x and you click on the now bigger cell, you actually clicked on the touch target of another, smaller cell from the previous zoom level.

I don't know if this is by design or not though (I've tried to find some docs regarding this issue, but haven't found anything). Any input/ideas on this matter?﻿ I know there's always the possibility of implementing the `ClickListener` manually, by listening on the `CustomLayout` touch events and mapping the touch event position to the now zoomed in/larger cell. But I wanted to know if it's possible to use the default `OnClickListener` for an easier and cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. Apparently I was scaling/translating the canvas instead of the view, so I guess it makes sense that the layout children couldn't take into consideration that the canvas has moved.

So, either scale/translate the entire view, not only its canvas (but this would result in lots of animations and dropped frames/jerkiness) or scale/translate only the canvas (this provides improved performance) and manage all the touch events, such as clicks, manually.﻿